# What's the best way to parse BigQuery Array into Columns

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I have a table like this

```
select 'Alice' as Name, ['a=1','b=2','c=3'];
```

and I want it to transform it into this

```
select 'Alice' as Name, 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c
```

What is the best way of doing this?

I am thinking of perhaps employing structs first

```
select 'Alice' as Name, [struct('a' as Letter, 1 as Number),struct('b' as Letter, 2 as Number) ,struct('c' as Letter, 3 as Number)]  as struct_column
```

Comment: Since there is no "dynamic column name", do you know beforehand which columns there is going to be in a query or do you really need "dynamic" column name?

Comment: Good question, no I don't need it to be dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't know in advance names and numbers of "to-be" columns - I recommend flattening instead as it is in below example (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Alice' AS Name, ['a=1','b=2','c=3'] attributes UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cheshire Cat', ['a=4', 'x=5'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'White Rabbit', ['a=6', 'c=7'] 
)
SELECT Name, 
  SPLIT(kv, '=')[OFFSET(0)] key, 
  SPLIT(kv, '=')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value  
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(attributes) kv
```

with result

```
Row Name            key value    
1   Alice           a   1    
2   Alice           b   2    
3   Alice           c   3    
4   Cheshire Cat    a   4    
5   Cheshire Cat    x   5    
6   White Rabbit    a   6    
7   White Rabbit    c   7
```

> i do know the attributes in advance ...

In this case below will work

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Alice' AS Name, ['a=1','b=2','c=3'] attributes UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cheshire Cat', ['a=4', 'b=5'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'White Rabbit', ['a=6', 'c=7'] 
)
SELECT Name,
  MAX(IF(key = 'a', value, NULL)) a,
  MAX(IF(key = 'b', value, NULL)) b,
  MAX(IF(key = 'c', value, NULL)) c
FROM (
  SELECT Name, 
    SPLIT(kv, '=')[OFFSET(0)] key, 
    SPLIT(kv, '=')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(attributes) kv   
)
GROUP BY Name
```

with result

```
Row Name            a       b       c    
1   Alice           1       2       3    
2   Cheshire Cat    4       5       null     
3   White Rabbit    6       null    7
```

Comment: Yeah i do know the attributes in advance, so would the best step after this be to just take the max(if(key =a,value,'') as a

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up  :o) and btw. I think to use NULL is more accurate than `''` in `max(if(key =a,value,'')`

Comment: I see safe_offset is 0 based but i don't get its existence if it's the same as offset?

Comment: you can use SAFE_OFFSET(0) but there is really no scenario when first (0) element in array does not exists  - that is why I use just OFFSET(0). While it is possible that array has just first (0) element and not second (1) so i use SAFE_OFFSET(1) to avoid error and rather to get just NULL in such case